# get_attribute method doesn't work on Python with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

So, I'm having trouble getting a element from a web page with Selenium and Python

The div in question is:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 broker-details">
    <div class=" ">
        <h6>MICHAEL CORLEONE</h6>
        <div> <strong>CODE: </strong> <span> 123456-X</span> </div>
        <div> <strong>Registration Date: </strong><span>18/03/2021</span> </div>
        <div> <strong>Situation: </strong><span>Active</span> </div>
        <form action="/citizen/details" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="registerNumber" value="123456-X">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> See More </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I use `find_elements()` to return the class elements as:

```
#setting the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'broker-details')[0].text
```

it returns something like:

'MICHAEL CORLEONE\nCODE: 123456-X\nRegistration Date: 18/03/2021\nSituation: Active\nSee More'

but when I try to use get_attribute to get a specific element, like:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'broker-details')[0].get_attribute('span')
```

it returns nothing, should I be referencing the blank space class? didn't even know it was possible, is there something im missing? I don't really know much about html/css/python please help.

Answer (score 0):

`.get_attribute()` is working fine, you are using it incorrectly. You are trying to use it to retrieve child elements but that's not it's purpose.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
```

Given the HTML above, `.get_attribute("class")` would return "btn btn-primary" or `.get_attribute("type")` would return "submit". It's used to return an attribute of an element, attribute being class or type. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) for more info.